# Can a cleric choose to channel damage or healing in a case by case basis?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The [Channel Energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric#TOC-Channel-Energy-Su-) section states that a good cleric can channel positive energy which either harms undead or heals living creatures.

Later in the section it states;

> Once this choice is made, it cannot be reversed.

This statement is preceded by;

> A neutral cleric of a neutral deity (or one who is not devoted to a particular deity) must choose whether she channels positive or negative energy.

So I'm assuming the first statement is referring ONLY to that neutral cleric statement.  Am I correct?

Basically my question is; Can a good cleric use channel energy to heal living creatures on a given round and then again to harm undead in another round?  (and vice versa for an evil cleric)

Answer (score 9):

Your assumption is correct; The 'choice' referred to is the choice between channeling positive or negative energy.  The full quote reads:

> A neutral cleric of a neutral deity (or one who is not devoted to a particular deity) must choose whether she channels positive or negative energy. Once this choice is made, it cannot be reversed.

That statement is self contained.  It doesn't refer to any other parts of the class ability.

Comment: +1 It's also worth noting that the Good cleric *can't* choose between damaging undead and healing living creatures - the effect simply depends on whether a living or undead creature is targeted.

Comment: But when channel energy is used, if there undead and living creatures in the area, a good cleric has to choose which channel to do?  The section reads "A good cleric (or a neutral cleric who worships a good deity) channels positive energy and can choose to deal damage to undead creatures or to heal living creatures."  That part is confusing.

Comment: @Dakeyras I don't think that's correct.  It says in the class ability description that the ability "affects all creatures of one type (either undead or living)".  It's pretty clear that you can only damage or heal one kind of creature at a time.  A good cleric can't choose to (for example) heal undead, but they can't damage undead and heal living with a single use of their ability.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl That's what I thought.  From my understanding, a good cleric can do both, harm undead or heal living but it would require separate uses of channel energy.